# Calling a variable from a Controller. Getting an error 'Undefined Variable: $pays'

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I want to read all the data from the payments table and get the transaction id and print it out on the users blade view. I'm not sure how to do it.

Can anyone offer me some guidance. This is the code which save the transaction id to the database.

```
public function MpesaRes(Request $request){
    \Log::info($request);

    $response = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $resData =  $response->Body->stkCallback->CallbackMetadata;
    $reCode =$response->Body->stkCallback->ResultCode;
    $resMessage =$response->Body->stkCallback->ResultDesc;
    $amountPaid = $resData->Item[0]->Value;
    $mpesaTransactionId = $resData->Item[1]->Value;
    $paymentPhoneNumber =$resData->Item[4]->Value;

    //replace the first 254 with 0
    $formatedPhone = str_replace("254","0",$paymentPhoneNumber);

    $payment = new Payment;
    $payment->amount = $amountPaid;
    $payment->mpesa_trans_id = $mpesaTransactionId;
    $payment->phone = $formatedPhone;
    $payment->save();

    \Log::info("Transaction ".$mpesaTransactionId." of amount ".$amountPaid." from phone number ".$formatedPhone." has been completed successfully");
}
```

**Return View**

```
public function confirmPayment(Request $request){
    $transId = $request->transactionId;
    $exists = Payment::where('mpesa_trans_id',$transId)->latest()->first();
    
    if(!$exists){
        $error = [
            "success" => false,
            "error" => "Unable to confirm your transaction code. Please contact admin.. :)"
        ];

        session($error);
        return back();
    }

    $message = [
        "success" => true,
        "message" => "Payment successful!"
    ];

    session($message);

    
    return view('/confirm', ['transId' => $transId]);
    
}
```

This is the code which is supposed to print the transaction id. But it ends up giving me an error 'Undefined variable:$pays'

```
<div class="login-inner-block">
    @foreach($pays as $pay)
        <div class="frm-grp">
            <label>@lang('Transaction Id')</label>
            <input type="text" name="transactionId" value="{{ old('transId') }}" placeholder="@lang('Example: OIB9FQP9H7')">
            <span class="text-box">Your Transaction Id Is</span>
            <span>{{$pay->mpesa_trans_id}}</span>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you have `$pays` defined?

Comment: Where is the logic to return the `view`?

Comment: @aynber That's what I was asking help for. I don't know where to add it.

Comment: @MaartenDev I edited my code and added it

Comment: Have you tried to send it to the view in the same way you're sending `$transId` to the view?

Comment: You have to pass the `$pays` value to the second argument of `view` like: `view('/confirm', ['transId' => $transId, 'pays' => $pays]);`

Comment: Yes. It still shows the error